# Google Sheets undo/redo function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, stack

I was looking through the network tab to see if redo/undo data is sent to the server in Google Sheets, and it seems it is not -- it seems it is local to the local user/device that is modifying the information.

What might the data structure look like to implement the undo/redo functionality? My guess is it would be a stack (i.e., array) with the last undo-able action pushed to the stack, something like this:

```
actions = [
    action_1,
    action_2
]
```

But what would the actual data structure look like for each of these actions? I suppose for a basic modification of a cell the text could be stored, but there are just so many possible things to do in Google Sheets, so it seems the 'action' could be almost infinitely complex.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, for example, how about creating the action log with OnEdit event trigger and OnChange event trigger for Google Apps Script? When the event trigger is used, when users edit the Google Spreadsheet, the log for each action can be retrieved. How about creating the undo/redo function using this? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize. [Ref1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), [Ref2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: @Tanaike yes, that would be great actually. Could you show an example script that logs the last undo/redo action?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Before I prepare the sample script, I have what I would like to confirm. In this case, Google Apps Script is used. Is this included in the direction you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike that's fine -- I'm more interested in just seeing the data structure that would be logged. Maybe just show a basic log for adding a cell value or doing a find-replace on multiple cells.

Comment: I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to achieve the functions for undo and redo for the Google Spreadsheet.
- You can use Google Apps Script.

I could understand like above. For this, how about this sample script? So please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Usage:

Please do the following flow for using the sample script.

1. Create new Spreadsheet and open the script editor.

   - If the 1st tab is not the name of `Sheet1`, please change it to `Sheet1`. In this sample script, as a test situation, the undo and redo functions for running to the sheet of `Sheet1` in the active Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.
2. Copy and paste the following sample script to the script editor, and save the script.
3. Install the installable OnEdit event trigger to the function `installedOnEdit`.

   - You can see the document for doing this at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). Please set `installedOnEdit` as OnEdit event trigger.
   - When you install the installable OnEdit event trigger, the authorization screen is opened. So please authorize the scopes.
4. Please close the Spreadsheet and reopen the Spreadsheet. By this, `onOpen()` is run by the simple trigger. And `offset` is cleared. And then, please open the script editor.
5. At the Spreadsheet, put manually "foo" to the cell "A1".

   - By this, the Spreadsheet of `logSpreadsheet` is created to the root folder. This is used as the log.
   - So only this one time, please wait for creating the Spreadsheet.
6. After you confirmed the created Spreadsheet at the root folder, put manually "bar" to the cell "A1".
7. Put manually "baz" to the cell "A1".

   - At this time, when you see the log Spreadsheet, you can see the following values to the cell "A1:A3". This is used for undo and redo function.

     ```
     {"range":"A1","value":"foo","oldValue":""}
     {"range":"A1","value":"bar","oldValue":"foo"}
     {"range":"A1","value":"baz","oldValue":"bar"}
     ```
8. Run the function `undo` at the script editor.

   - By this, the value of cell "A1" is changed from `baz` to `bar`.
9. Run the function `undo` at the script editor.

   - By this, the value of cell "A1" is changed from `bar` to `foo`.
10. Run the function `undo` at the script editor.

    - By this, the value of cell "A1" is changed from `foo` to the empty. Because the initial situation is the empty.
11. Run the function `redo` at the script editor.

    - By this, the value of cell "A1" is changed from `foo` to `bar`.
12. Run the function `redo` at the script editor.

    - By this, the value of cell "A1" is changed from `bar` to `baz`.
13. Run the function `redo` at the script editor.

    - By this, the value of cell "A1" is not changed. Because this situation is the latest one.

### Sample script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function onOpen() {
  prop.setProperty("offset", "0");
}

function getSheet() {
  var logId = prop.getProperty("logSpreadsheetId");
  if (logId) {
    return SpreadsheetApp.openById(logId).getSheets()[0];
  }
  throw new Error("Please edit a cell in the Spreadsheet. By this, the Spreadsheet for logging is created.");
}

// Undo function
function undo() {
  var logsheet = getSheet();
  var offset = Number(prop.getProperty("offset"));
  var lastRow = logsheet.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow + offset > 0) {
    var log = logsheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).offset(offset, 0).getValue();
    var obj = JSON.parse(log);
    sheet.getRange(obj.range).setValue(obj.oldValue);
    prop.setProperty("offset", offset - 1);
  }
}

// Redo function
function redo() {
  var logsheet = getSheet();
  var offset = Number(prop.getProperty("offset")) + 1;
  var lastRow = logsheet.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow + offset <= lastRow) {
    var log = logsheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).offset(offset, 0).getValue();
    var obj = JSON.parse(log);
    sheet.getRange(obj.range).setValue(obj.value);
    prop.setProperty("offset", offset);
  }
}

// Please set the installable OnEdit event trigger to this function.
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var logId = prop.getProperty("logSpreadsheetId")
  var ss;
  if (logId) {
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(logId);
  } else {
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("logSpreadsheet");
    prop.setProperty("logSpreadsheetId", ss.getId());
  }
  var log = {range: e.range.getA1Notation(), value: "value" in e ? e.value : "", oldValue: "oldValue" in e ? e.oldValue : ""};
  ss.getSheets()[0].appendRow([JSON.stringify(log)]);
}
```

### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. Unfortunately, the complicated actions might not be able to be used. For example, in the current script cannot use to edit the multiple cells. I deeply apologize for this. When you want to add more complicated  actions, it is required to modify the script for each situation. Please be careful this.
- In the current stage, when the cell value is deleted by clicking the delete button, the old value is not included in the event object. So when you want to test the delete of value, please click the cell and delete each character in the cell by the backspace button. By this, the old value is included in the event object. Please be careful this.
- I think that if you want to make more complicated actions, to overwrite the Spreadsheet with the revision data might be suitable. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions)

### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)